# Can't get Blob info from derby DB

Tags: java, blob, derby, razorsql

I have Derby DB V 10.12.1.1 with one table:

```
CREATE TABLE APP.JACKRABBIT_X0020_CORE_NODE 
( 
   NODE_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
   NODE_DATA BLOB(2147483647) NOT NULL 
);
```

There are some rows which I can read without any problem but there is one row which I can't read

It has strange representation in data set

[image]

When I trying to export\backup this table using RazorSQL I have next error: `Java exception: ': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` There wasn't any problem with exporting other tables (or the same table but without this problem line)

Is there some way to understand what problem with this specific line (corrupted BLOB or so)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

11/11/2015 added

java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: '-1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.noStateChangeException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at derby.App.selectNode(App.java:113)
    at derby.App.main(App.java:26)
Caused by: ERROR XJ001: Java exception: '-1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BasePage.getHeaderAtSlot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.restorePortionLongColumn(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.OverflowInputStream.fillByteHolder(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BufferedByteHolderInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.SQLBinary.readExternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.SQLBinary.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.SQLBinary.getString(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more

Comment: Can you get the full exception back-trace, not just the one-liner?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I've added trace of exception

Comment: Unfortunately, you still didn't get the **full** back-trace -- see the "3 more" at the end? You have to dig down to the bottom to unearth the root cause. See http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: However, if the root cause turns out to be "-1 at o.a.d.i.store.raw.data.BasePage.getHeaderAtSlot", your database has become corrupt.